# How to make multiple api web server calls and have an activity indicator active inside a tableViewCell while 2nd api is being called?

Tags: swift, rest, asynchronous, uitableview

Currently I am calling two web service apis, one for data and one for video.  If I call the video api after the data one, the data cells populate and after the video api finishes connecting the video cell "pops out" because there was no cell for it before it completed loading.  I tried reloading the tableview only after the video api had finished making its call but the loading time increased dramatically. Is there a way to have all the data from the the first api available and have an activity indicator running inside the video cell while the video api is being called?  Here is my code, its been abbreviated to save space:

Get the data json:

```
 func getJSON (urlString: String) {

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let urlConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: urlConfig)
        task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if (error == nil) {
              self.updateDetailShowInfo(data!)
              spinner.hide()
              let videoURL = ""
              self.getVideoJSON(videoURL)
            } else {
               spinner.hide()
              self.showNetworkError()
            }
          }
        }
        task!.resume()
      }
```

get the video json:

```
func getVideoJSON (urlString: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let urlConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: urlConfig)
    task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if (error == nil) {
          self.updateVideo(data!)
          spinner.hide()
        } else {
          spinner.hide()
          self.showNetworkError()
        }
      }
    }
    task!.resume()
  }
```

update data (this was really long so I only showed the data being added to local arrays after they were gathered):

```
func updateDetailShowInfo (data: NSData!) {
    do {
      let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

      let banner = jsonResult["banner"] as? String ?? ""

      detailsArray.append(showInfo)
      bannerArray.append(banner)
      overViewArray.append(overview)
      totalResultsArray.append(detailsArray)
      totalResultsArray.append(bannerArray)
      totalResultsArray.append(overViewArray)
      totalResultsArray.append(castLocalArray)
      photosArray.append(poster)
      photosArray.append(fanart)
      photosArray.append(artwork)
      totalResultsArray.append(photosArray)
      exploreArray.append(exploreInfo)
      totalResultsArray.append(exploreArray)
    }
    catch {
      showNetworkError()
    }
    DetailTvTableView.reloadData()
  }
```

update video data (only showing added to array):

```
 func updateVideo (data: NSData!) {
    do {
      let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            videoURL.append(videoView!)
            totalResultsArray.append(videoURL)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      showNetworkError()
    }
    self.DetailTvTableView.reloadData()
  }
```

tableView:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return totalResultsArray.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0: return bannerArray.count
    case 1: return videoURL.count
    case 2: return overViewArray.count
    case 3: return min(1, castLocalArray.count)
    case 4: return detailsArray.count
    case 5: return socialArray.count
    case 6: return exploreArray.count
    case 7: return min(1, photosArray.count)

    default: fatalError("Unknown Selection")
    }
  }
```

video cellForRowAtIndexPath in tableView:

```
  case 1:
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("videoDetail", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
      VideoOnDetailCell

      cell.videoDetailWebView.delegate = cell
      cell.videoDetailWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

        self.DetailTvTableView.rowHeight = 200
        cell.videoDetailWebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(cell.videoDetailWebView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(200)\" src=\"\(videoURL[indexPath.row])/?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
      }
```

video cell:

```
class VideoOnDetailCell: UITableViewCell, UIWebViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var videoDetailWebView: UIWebView!
  @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


  func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activityIndicator.hidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
  }
  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
    activityIndicator.hidden = true
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't your UI freezing?

Comment: It's not freezing, I have a full screen spinner active while the apis are being called.  I omitted it from the code to save space.